# Error creating a copy of a subclass

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a basic enemy class that is a subclass of SKSpriteNode, I have another subclass of it. In my GameScene when I try to initialize an object from that subclass everything works perfectly, but when I try to create a copy of that object I get an error:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(texture:color:size:)'
```

that error refers to the basic class Enemy not the subclass EnemyA

Enemy basic class:

```
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {

    init(image: String, health: Int, damage: CGFloat, moveSpeed: CGFloat){
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: image)

        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

    }
```

EnemyA subclass:

```
class EnemyA: Enemy {

    override init(image: String, health: Int, damage: CGFloat, moveSpeed: CGFloat) {
        super.init(image: image, health: health, damage: damage, moveSpeed: moveSpeed) 
    }
```

creating the clone in GameScene:

```
        let enemyA = EnemyA(image: "Enemy_Sprite0", health: 10, damage: 20, moveSpeed: 5)

        let clone = enemyA.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        clone.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        addChild(clone)
```

Comment: the error says that you haven't declared or implemented the call you are making to the super within this line (texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size()). implement that and the error will go away.

Comment: I already managed to fix the issue, Thank you.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please post it and mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue of trying to copy a subclass of an SKSpriteNode. My solution was to override the copy() function (in the subclass). In that overridden copy() function I called /used the subclass's custom initializer -- my custom initializer calls super.init(texture:color:size). Passing in the necessary init parameters in the subclassed copy seems to do the trick.